# Setting frame for background colour of Selected tableviewCell working fine in iOS 7 but not in iOS 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want to set frame for background colour of selected tableviewCell. I am using the following code.

```
UIView * cellBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
cellBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
UIView * selectedCellColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 300, 44)];
selectedCellColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
[cellBackgroundView addSubview:selectedCellColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = cellBackgroundView;
```

Which is working fine in iOS7. Even Tableview selection also not working in iOS6.

Following code working fine in Both iOS6 and iOS 7. But here i am not able to set frame for background colour of selected tableViewCell.

```
UIView *selectedCellColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
[selectedCellColor setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
selectedCellColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0
                                                    green:50.0/255.0
                                                     blue:50.0/255.0
                                                    alpha:1.0];
cell.selectedBackgroundView=selectedCellColor;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` (not simply `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`. The reason is that now your cell is the correct size. Do not hard-code the cell size; get it as the `bounds` of the cell you are handed.

Now draw a UIImage in that size, constructing your frame-like drawing (the image itself is clear to begin with). Put it in a UIImageView and set the cell's selected background view to that image view.

This will work in iOS 6 and iOS 7.

Example (color and size arbitrary, just for illustration purposes):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(cell.bounds.size, NO, 0);
// change this color as you like
[[UIColor redColor] setFill];
// fiddle with this size as you like
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(10,10,300,25)] fill];
UIImage* im = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageView* iv = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:im];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = iv;
```

Comment: I tried like this    UIImageView *bGImage =[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
    bGImage.backgroundColor =[UIColor clearColor];
    UIView * selectedCellColor = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 300, 44)];
    selectedCellColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:50.0/255.0 green:50.0/255.0 blue:50.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    [bGImage addSubview:selectedCellColor];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bGImage;   But tableview selected colour not changing in iOS6. But its working fine in iOS7

Comment: But you didn't do what I said (draw the image).

Comment: I've added code to show you how to draw the image. For more about how to draw, see my full discussion here: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch15.html

Comment: Thanks! Just to clarify: the problem is that on iOS 6 you are not in control of how the selected background view is manipulated by the framework. This is why you use an image view: you are in control of the image, so now you can do what you want to do.

Comment: That's why i am not able to set frame in iOS 6. Thanks again for your clarification.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

Try this instead:

```
[cell.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
UIView *selectedBG = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
[selectedBG setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
[cell.selectedBackgroundView addSubview:selectedBG];
```

Comment: With the above code when i click on cell selected colour(green) covering total cell. But i need some gap from x origin like (10,0,310,44)

Comment: Try this when creating your selectedBG
`UIView *selectedBG = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,0,cell.contentView.frame.size.width-10, cell.contentView.frame.size.height)];`

Comment: @user3373798 You are not in charge of the size of the `selectedBackgroundView`. You must respond to the size that it actually will be.

Comment: Even i put cell.contentView.frame.size.width-100, Total cell background colour is  coming on click